# Azure UI access with puppeteer: login with service principal

Tags: azure, ui-automation, azureportal

I need to login to Azure UI (portal) to download ADF ARM template manually (no CLI/API available)

I need to automate this action so I started with puppeteer as a tool

It requires user's login and password, but I can't use it in PROD because it has MFA enabled

Any ideas how could I login to Azure portal with service principal?

I'll execute puppeteer from Azure DevOps which is added as an Enterprise app to Azure AD, maybe this integration could be used somehow?

PS if there's something more suitable than puppeteer I'll be happy to use alternative

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to login azure portal with a service principal.

In your case, I think puppeteer is the best option, the workaround is to create a new work account in Azure AD without MFA.