# Login Via service principal in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure. I am looking for way to login via Service Principal to Azure Portal.

For example, there are some access permissions which are available only for Service principal. I have user id and credentials for that Sp. I am not looking for way to write a script and do it.

I want to find if it's possible to impersonate that Sp as a user for Azure portal.

Comment: The main reason to use a Service Principal is to manage and access resources without user interaction --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to login to the Azure portal with a service principal, but you can [sign in with a service principal via Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal) using [password-based or certificate-based authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

See also:

[Login as a service principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719507/how-to-log-in-to-azure-service-principal)

[Azure UI access with service principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097277/azure-ui-access-with-puppeteer-login-with-service-principal)